# overflow: auto; not working for my navbar

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML navbar, i have it set up to where the  has a `padding` of `20px 45px` however, it shows the horizontal padding correctly, but the vertical padding just overflows. I've tried putting `overflow: auto;` in the parent div but it doesn't work.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: HI - note that you can embed JS/HTML/CSS directly into your question - which makes it much easier for others to answer.

Comment: What is it that you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: block` on the `a` tags, so that the padding can be effective:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: hidden;` rather than `overflow: auto;`

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```